# How to make marker images?

Tags: image-processing, image, marker

In the docs for `GrowCutComponents[]` there are many examples of masks, but I don't know how to make one for myself. I suppose they are using the drawing tools in some way (which I have never used), but a straightforward application of it gave this error:

[image]

Are there any examples of how to make a marker mask? Perhaps in a tutorial or in the refs for another symbol?

Comment: Maybe you need more than one marker? Also, try to `Binarize` the marker image, to make sure it's not antialiased

Comment: @nikie but really I'm asking about what are the actual steps of using draw tools to make them

Answer (score 6):

A toy example :

- Take an image
- draw some line on it with the Drawing Tools
- select the whole image. There should be a orange contour line with orange handlers, like in the image below. You can do that by clicking out of the cell, then inside the cell.
- right-click to have the contextual menu, then "Graphics Editing", then "create Mask"

I have experienced some bugs with the Drawing Tool, specially with Mathematica Version 11.2 (Windows 7 in my case). Hope you will not have to deal with them.

[image]

Result :

> [image]

Comment: I have never found information about that. Just discovered it now (!).

Comment: This is great!  I was also wondering about doing it programatically though... any thoughts on that?