# How to create a binary mask of an image

Tags: image-processing

Consider an image (`img`) as

[image]

I want to create a binary mask which will exactly cover the foreground.

If I do the following

```
b = DeleteSmallComponents@FillingTransform@Binarize[img];
skeleton = SkeletonTransform[b];
pruned = Pruning[skeleton, 1, 1];
mask = InverseDistanceTransform[pruned]
```

I get

[image]

You can see that the head is not completely white as desired and this may be due to the fact that the bottom of the head is connected to the boundary of image. Secondly, near the neck (as indicated by the green line), some pixels are black which should be white.

[image]

How can I fix these two issues?

Comment: You could try `MorphologicalBinarize` instead of `Binarize` and also play with the second argument.

Comment: `MorphologicalBinarize[img, {.1, .5}, CornerNeighbors -> False]` is a good starting point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
img2 = FillingTransform@
  GeodesicClosing[MorphologicalBinarize[img, {.1, .5}, CornerNeighbors -> False], 10]
```

> [image]

A smoothed outline (thanks to [Rahul](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144814/280)):

```
Binarize@CurvatureFlowFilter[img2, 3]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

This approach uses `ImageData` to work on the lines, rather than the whole image. After a few manipulations, it detects the first and last white pixel on each line and turn the whole segment to `1` (i.e. white).

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw1iJ.png"]
edges = EdgeDetect[img, 2]
data = ImageData@edges;
Table[line = data[[j]]; pos = Flatten@Position[line, 1];
  If[Length[pos] > 1, data[[j, pos[[1]] ;; pos[[-1]]]] = 1];
  , {j, Length@data}];
Image@data
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `GrowCutComponents[]`, one can obtain this :

[image]

A little bit lifting with Dilation/Erosion will probably improve the result.

How to use `GrowCutComponents[]` ?

you have to create the 2 masks and evaluate the following :

[image]

One can create the masks with Drawing Tools [see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164083/5467)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution motivated by Alexey.

```
Opening[DeleteSmallComponents[
  ColorNegate[
   RegionBinarize[img, {{1, 1}}, 0.1, Method -> "MeanEuclidean"]], 
  CornerNeighbors -> False], 1]
```

The result is:

[image]